# SQL combining statements

Tags: sql

Okay, I have to figure out how to only show the employee with the top sick hours by department.  IF a deparment has multiple employees tied for sick hours, it has to show all.

The first query, gives me every person in the department sorted by SickLeaveHours.
The second query tells me the top sick leave hours by department.

How do I get the top query to limit the results based on the bottom query.

```
Select FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Name, (SickLeaveHours), Department.DepartmentID as DepartmentID, HumanResources.Department.Name
 FROM HumanResources.Employee, HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory, Person.Contact, HumanResources.Department
Where Employee.EmployeeID=EmployeeDepartmentHistory.EmployeeID and Employee.ContactID=Contact.ContactID and EndDate is Null  and HumanResources.Department.DepartmentID=EmployeeDepartmentHistory.DepartmentID
Order by SickLeaveHours DESC


Select DepartmentID, Max(SickLeaveHours) as 'Top Sick Leave Hours'
From HumanResources.Employee, HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory
Where EmployeeDepartmentHistory.EmployeeID=Employee.EmployeeID and EmployeeDepartmentHistory.EndDate is Null
Group by DepartmentID
Order by 'Top Sick Leave Hours' DESC
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to save your bottom query into a temp table and select from it based on the "Top Sick Leave Hours" Might not be the best solution depending on what else you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Does this windowing function work for you? I do not have your environment to test this to make sure that my syntax is totally correct...

```
Select FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Name, 
MAX(SickLeaveHours) OVER (PARTITION BY Department.DepartmentID ) as MaxSickLeaveHours,     
Department.DepartmentID as DepartmentID, HumanResources.Department.Name
 FROM HumanResources.Employee, HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory, Person.Contact, HumanResources.Department
Where Employee.EmployeeID=EmployeeDepartmentHistory.EmployeeID and Employee.ContactID=Contact.ContactID and EndDate is Null  and HumanResources.Department.DepartmentID=EmployeeDepartmentHistory.DepartmentID
Order by SickLeaveHours DESC
```

Comment: Thanks.  This helps a lot.  But, I think it is just assigning hte Max hours to each employee instead of choosing the employees iwth the max hours.

Comment: Max hours by department that is.